# Python: improve code efficency, focus on plot part usign matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, charts

I briefly report my situation:

I'm running simulations in python and I plot a chart during data processing iteration.
The problem are:

1. The dynamic plot I made, works well, but after some(500 more or less) iterations, it starts to go slowly, taking more than the pause time I decided for each iteration. So I need to close the figure window to make it again fast, but after 200 iterations, it becomes again slowly and so on...
2. Since I run simulation with over 40000 iterations, improvements may arrive to reduce almost 1 min my simulation's time.

Here there the code I'm talking about:

```
uxs =[]
uxP =[]
i=0
for z in Ti:
    # Unscendet Kalman Filter operations
    i+=1
    ukf.predict(dt, fx_args=(Te[floor(i/4.)],u))
    ukf.update(z)
    uxs.append(ukf.x.copy())
    uxP.append(ukf.P.copy())
    # Create Temporary Version of uxs and uxP, in this way I can use them as a numpy array
    uxsTemp = np.array(uxs)
    uxPTemp = np.array(uxP)
    # Dynamic graph
    plt.figure("Live Temperature")
    ax = plt.gca()
    t = np.arange(0,uxsTemp[:,0].size,1) # Create a timeline with step 1, longer as the current data number
    plt.plot(t, Ti[0:uxsTemp[:,0].size], 'ro', label='External measures (Ti(t))')
    plt.plot(t, uxsTemp[:,0],'b', label='Estimated (Ti(t))')
    if(i%50==0):
        print("mod:"+str(i%50) +"\nP:"+str(ukf.P[0,0]))
        circle1 = plt.Circle((uxsTemp[:,0].size, ukf.x[0]), sqrt(ukf.P[0,0]),    color='g', fill=True)
        ax.add_artist(circle1)
        ax.plot((uxsTemp[:,0].size, ukf.x[0]),'ys', color='black') # I put a yellow point on current point
    plt.xlim(uxsTemp[:,0].size - 10,uxsTemp[:,0].size + 5)
    plt.ylim(-5,40)
    plt.show(block=False)
    pause(0.00000001)
```

I hope someone have a possible solutions. Since when I close the figure window, it then re-opens and go faste, I guess something like clear variables may help me. But I don't know how to deal with it.

PS: another problem is the following line that does not work, I think because it is overlapped by red points of the other data:

```
ax.plot((uxsTemp[:,0].size, ukf.x[0]),'ys', color='black') # I put a yellow point on current point
```

But actually I don't care that much about the last one at this step, the first one has priority.

Comment: It seems you are adding at least 2 new plots to the figure in each step. So after some time you have thousands of line plots in your figure. I would guess you should look at other questions on how to animate matplotlib, especially using `FuncAnimation` and `.set_data`. (As [ask] tells you, always state in how far similar questions are not helping.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you for your suggestion. I already read examples about it. But I had issues trying to set it properly

Comment: The idea is of course to show the code you have issues with, see [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'll make my minimal example and post it. Thank you